# Estimating approximate confidence interval of logit(p)

Tags: statistics

I have the following problem for which I do not know if my solution is correct or not.

Let $X_1 , ... , X_n \sim Bernoulli(p)$.

Let $logit(p) = \frac{p}{1-p}$, let $S_n = \sum_{j=1}^n X_j$.

I want to find of the limit of logit($\frac{S_n}{n}$) and its confidence interval of level 95% 
I call $\frac{S_n}{n} = \overline{S_n}$
This is what I have done:

Using the TLC, I can write: 
$$ \sqrt{n} ( \overline{S_n} - p) \to \mathcal{N}(0,p(1-p)) $$

So using delta method I find that:

$$ \sqrt{n} ( logit(\overline{S_n}) - log(\frac{p}{1-p})) \to \mathcal{N}(0,p(1-p)[\frac{d}{dp}logit(p)]^2) $$

$$ \sqrt{n} ( logit(\overline{S_n}) - \log{\frac{1}{1-p}}) \to \mathcal{N}(0,\frac{1}{p(1-p)}) $$

I now assume that I have n = 500 and $S_{500} = 380$

I know that confidence interval are of the form:

$$ \overline{X} \pm Z_{\alpha/2} \sqrt{\frac{\sigma^2}{n}} $$

In my case, I have that $\overline{X} = logit(\frac{380}{500})$, $n=500$ and $\sigma^2 = \frac{1}{p(1-p)}$ with $p = \frac{380}{500}$.

Can someone check if this is right?

Comment: In your third line, *logit* should involve a logarithm, while $\frac{p}{1-p}$ represents  the odds

Comment: @Henry Oh yeah, misprint, going to edit